# Passing state from one component to another (not child component) using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have my search bar in a `Navbar` component which is constant with all screens so it is in my `App.js` file. Now, I want to store the string that user puts in the Input (in `Navbar.jsx`), bring it to `App.js` and then pass it to my other components. I am not sure how to do that. The three files that I am talking about are given:

1. `App.js` (the file containing the `Navbar` and my Other components)
2. `Navbar.jsx` (The file containing the input search bar from where we are getting the string)
3. `Homepage.jsx` (the page where I want to access the search bar string to filter my results)

**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";

import {
  Navbar,
  Homepage,
  Crypto,
  Exchanges,
  Settings,
} from "./components/index";
import { Layout } from "antd";
import Dock from "./components/Dock/Dock";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="navbar">
        <Navbar />
        <Dock />
      </div>
      <div className="main">
        <Layout>
          <div className="routes>">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/">
                <Homepage />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/cryptocurrencies">
                <Crypto />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/exchanges">
                <Exchanges />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/settings">
                <Settings />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Layout>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Homepage.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Homepage.css";
import CryptoCard from "../Card/Card";
import axios from "axios";

const Homepage = () => {
  const [coinData, setCoinData] = useState([], () => {
    const localData = localStorage.getItem("coinData");
    return localData ? JSON.parse(localData) : [];
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com/coins",
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "API_KEY",
      },
    };

    axios
      .request(options)
      .then((response) => {
        setCoinData(response.data.data.coins);
        // persist in localStorage
        localStorage.setItem(
          "coinData",
          JSON.stringify(response.data.data.coins)
        );
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);

  console.log("Coins names");
  coinData.forEach(function (coin) {
    console.log(coin.name);
  });

  return (
    <div className="homepage">
      <div className="heading">
        <h1>Discover</h1>
        <hr className="line" />
      </div>
      <div className="cards-container">
        {(coinData || []).map((coin) => (
          <CryptoCard
            name={coin.name}
            coinUrl={coin.websiteUrl}
            duration="4 minutes ago"
            symbol={coin.symbol}
            rank={coin.rank}
            exchanges={coin.numberOfExchanges}
            price={coin.price}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Homepage;
```

**Navbar.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import Badge from "@mui/material/Badge";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import Menu from "@mui/material/Menu";
import AccountCircle from "@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle";
import NotificationsIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Notifications";
import MoreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoreVert";
import Icon from "../../images/logo.png";
import Brightness3Icon from "@mui/icons-material/Brightness3";
import WbSunnyTwoToneIcon from "@mui/icons-material/WbSunnyTwoTone";
import "./Navbar.css";
import HomeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Home";

var notification = 1;

export default function PrimarySearchAppBar() {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(true);
  const darkModeToggle = () => {
    setDarkMode(!darkMode);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (darkMode) {
      document.body.classList.add("dark");
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove("dark");
    }
  }, [darkMode]);

  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const [mobileMoreAnchorEl, setMobileMoreAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const isMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const isMobileMenuOpen = Boolean(mobileMoreAnchorEl);

  const handleProfileMenuOpen = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleMobileMenuClose = () => {
    setMobileMoreAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    handleMobileMenuClose();
  };

  const handleMobileMenuOpen = (event) => {
    setMobileMoreAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const menuId = "primary-search-account-menu";
  const renderMenu = (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
      anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: "top",
        horizontal: "right",
      }}
      id={menuId}
      keepMounted
      transformOrigin={{
        vertical: "top",
        horizontal: "right",
      }}
      open={isMenuOpen}
      onClose={handleMenuClose}
    >
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>My account</MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  );

  const mobileMenuId = "primary-search-account-menu-mobile";
  const renderMobileMenu = (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={mobileMoreAnchorEl}
      anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: "top",
        horizontal: "right",
      }}
      id={mobileMenuId}
      keepMounted
      transformOrigin={{
        vertical: "top",
        horizontal: "right",
      }}
      open={isMobileMenuOpen}
      onClose={handleMobileMenuClose}
    >
      <MenuItem>
        <IconButton size="large" color="inherit" style={{ marginTop: "3px" }}>
          {"day" === "night" ? (
            <Brightness3Icon style={{ color: "#000000" }} />
          ) : (
            <WbSunnyTwoToneIcon style={{ color: "#000000" }} />
          )}
        </IconButton>
        {"day" === "night" ? <p>Dark Mode</p> : <p> Light Mode</p>}
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>
        <IconButton
          size="large"
          aria-label="show 17 new notifications"
          color="inherit"
        >
          <Badge badgeContent={notification} color="error">
            <NotificationsIcon />
          </Badge>
        </IconButton>
        <p>Notifications</p>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}>
        <IconButton
          size="large"
          aria-label="account of current user"
          aria-controls="primary-search-account-menu"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          color="inherit"
        >
          <AccountCircle />
        </IconButton>
        <p>Profile</p>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>
        <IconButton size="large" aria-haspopup="true" color="inherit">
          <HomeIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <p>Home</p>
      </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  );

  //RENDERING ON SCREEN
  return (
    <div className="navbar-container">
      <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
        <AppBar
          position="static"
          style={{ background: "#171721" }}
          elevation={0}
        >
          <Toolbar>
            <img src={Icon} alt="alt" className="app-logo" />
            <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} />
            <div className="search">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Find your Exchange or Currency..."
                className="search-bar"
              />
            </div>
            <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} />
            <Box sx={{ display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" } }}>
              <IconButton size="large" color="inherit">
                {darkMode === true ? (
                  <a className="mode" onClick={darkModeToggle}>
                    <WbSunnyTwoToneIcon style={{ color: "#B7B7BA" }} />
                  </a>
                ) : (
                  <a className="mode" onClick={darkModeToggle}>
                    <Brightness3Icon style={{ color: "#B7B7BA" }} />
                  </a>
                )}
              </IconButton>
              <IconButton
                size="large"
                aria-label="show 17 new notifications"
                color="inherit"
                style={{ color: "#B7B7BA" }}
              >
                <Badge badgeContent={notification} color="error">
                  <NotificationsIcon />
                </Badge>
              </IconButton>
              <IconButton
                size="large"
                edge="end"
                aria-label="account of current user"
                aria-controls={menuId}
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}
                color="inherit"
                style={{ color: "#B7B7BA" }}
              >
                <AccountCircle />
              </IconButton>
            </Box>
            <Box sx={{ display: { xs: "flex", md: "none" } }}>
              <IconButton
                size="large"
                aria-label="show more"
                aria-controls={mobileMenuId}
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onClick={handleMobileMenuOpen}
                color="inherit"
              >
                <MoreIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </Box>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        {renderMobileMenu}
        {renderMenu}
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How do I pass state from `Navbar` to `App` and then to my `Homepage`?

*Not a part of the question but if you have any insight on how to filter the result from the `map` function in homepage, please let me know. Would appreciate the help!*

Comment: You should use React Context: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html.

Comment: you can also use the ref to pass the object beside every hierarchy of trees if you don't need an update and want to use the value in functions with user interaction. https://twitter.com/realamirhe/status/1362457891609919489

Comment: Will look into context! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply declare that state in App.js and use it as props in your components Navbar and Homepage

App.js

```
import "./App.css";

import {
  Navbar,
  Homepage,
  Crypto,
  Exchanges,
  Settings,
} from "./components/index";
import { Layout } from "antd";
import Dock from "./components/Dock/Dock";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="navbar">
        <Navbar  searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue}/>
        <Dock />
      </div>
      <div className="main">
        <Layout>
          <div className="routes>">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/">
                <Homepage setSearchValue={setSearchValue} searchValue={searchValue}/>
              ...          
  );
}

export default App;
```

Homepage.jsx

```
const Homepage = ({setSearchValue, searchValue}) => {
...
```

Navbar.jsx

```
const Navbar= ({setSearchValue, searchValue}) => {
...
```

If you have more components to handle or even grandchilds, it can be redundant to use props so I advise you learn about redux or the useContext hook to manage your state

Comment: How do I declare the state in App.js when the value is in Navbar.jsx?

Comment: Just remove "  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(true);" from Navbar.jsx and put it in App.jsx, now you'll get darkMode and setDarkMode from your props in Navbar.jsx

Comment: I am sorry, dark mode is irrelevant. I am talking about passing the search result from the input in Navbar

Comment: Ah my bad! But still it's the exact same answer, just decalre const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState(""); in app.jsx and use it in your props

Comment: And I can pass the setSearchValue as props as well? Isn't that a function?

Comment: Yes it is and yes you can pass function as parameters it's called a callback function I believe